# Show html content returned from server in an iframe in uibModal

Tags: angularjs, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I tried a lot but I don't know why it is not working. Here's my modal structure:

```
<div id="modalID">
  <div class="modal-header"></div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe srcdoc="htmlText">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting html content to be displayed from the server. It is processed as follows:

```
controller('ModalCtrl',function(text){
  $scope.htmlText=$sce.trustAsHtml(text);
}
```

I'm trying to display htmlText in an iframe when the modal is opened. I'm uisng $uibModal service for the modal. Everything works fine when I use div element with ng-bind-html instead of iframe. But I want to display the data in the iframe. 
Please propose a solution, I have tried everything and wasted two days on this but not able to make it work. Thanks in advance.

I also tried directive approach but it is also not working. Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong?

```
.directive("previewHTML", function () {
    function link(scope, element) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        var element0 = element[0];
        element0.appendChild(iframe);
        var body = iframe.contentDocument.body;

        scope.$watch('content', function () {
            body.innerHTML = scope.content;
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            content: '='
        }
    };
});


<div class="modal-body">
   <preview-html content="htmlText"></preview-html>
</div>
```

I'm getting iframe as follows:
[image]

Comment: did you try with srcdoc="{{htmlText}}" don't think angular will process a srcdoc attribute to parse the value.  Also personally made a directive that would load text into an iframe element believe I just used the document from the iframe element that I'd apply the directive to

Comment: @shaunhusain Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Here it is

```
    .directive("previewHTML", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<iframe height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr('srcdoc', attrs.iframeSrc);
        }
    };
})
```

HTML Markup

```
<div class="modal-body text-left">
    <preview-html data-iframe-src="{{htmlText}}"></preview-html>
</div>
```